# How to analyze webRTC internal dump

Tags: python, google-chrome, networking, webrtc, data-analysis

I have downloaded json dump of webRTC from chrome://webrtc-internals/. Now I want to analyze the logs and need to plot graphs. In the stats there are multiple fields which I don't understand. Can someone explain what these fields stand for and how can I use them to plot video quality and bitrate vs timestamp graph.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

You can look at https://fippo.github.io/webrtc-dump-importer/ which I wrote to import the dump and plot graphs. The format exported by webrtc-internals is not specified and change at any time but the javascript implementation has worked for a couple of years now.

Plotting video quality largely depends on how you define that. The dump gives you just a lot of numbers.